# Whats the proper way to use a REST API in an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I want to practice and brush up on some web development. My path is currently to write a REST Web API and then develop a client/front end to consume it.

I have chosen to use ASP.NET Web API as the type. I understand creating the REST API but am having trouble understanding the best way to consume it. I would like to continue using C# as it is my most practiced language, but I know it is somewhat lacking compared to js when it comes to web development.

I have had trouble finding the best way to consume a REST api still using C#. I know I can use an ASP.NET MVC project, but this is still pretty HTML driven, and I am not sure the best way to actually use an API controller when dealing with the MVC architecture. Would you use the controller in MVC to hit your API controller?

I know with .NET Core I have seen the controller now functions as both types of controllers. But how does this work? If I wanted to display products to a user, would the controller have two actions? One to get the products from a database and one to return a view using those products returned? Or is it one actions that does all the work?

Any other recommendations to consume a rest API with a web client outside of these options?

Comment: Remember that you have to write code that actually executes on the client side in Javascript. The client can't execute C#.

Comment: I saw some information on a new tech called "Blazor" that may be an alternative to writing javascript? are you familiar with this at all?

Comment: I've _heard of it_, and yes I believe it allows you to write code (that eventually gets translated to something the browser can run) using C#.

Comment: If you are new to web development, I would strongly suggest **not** starting with Blazor.

Comment: I'm more new to the "front-end" side of web dev. I have developed API's and server side code in c# to get/retrieve data and do complex business logic, and i have called API's from window's based clients, just not from web pages etc.....

Comment: usually the client will call your API,  there's no real point your server side calling your own rest api to then serve it to the client as html.

Comment: so would you combine both "controllers" into one. One that has your REST actions but also return a view? I have read some articles about combining these two, but im not sure what it LOOKS like, or how the calls are structured....

Comment: If you want to call web API from web pages JavaScript is the way. JQuery is a framework available on top of JavaScript.You can use jQuery to make requests to web API.

Comment: WebAPI is a back end, MVC can consume a many sorts of backends, as well as JS, and C#. None is "lacking" as much as each has it's own purpose.

Comment: MVC controllers can return data too in addition to views. And jQuery can make request to MVC controllers too.

Comment: you may like angular.  If you  do want to write MVC frontend in .net core then I would write the api in one project and the client mvc app in another.